# Best way to recover a partition from my HDD that I lost when my computer shut down while I was expanding the partition from 800GB to 1TB?

Tags: hard-drive, gparted, data-recovery

I had two partitions, and I deleted the first partition (NTFS) to expand the second and keep only one partition (EXT4). However, while performing this operation in GParted, my computer shut down, and upon reconnecting the HDD, the partition was no longer there. Can anyone tell me if there is a way to recover this partition? I know about Photorec, but it retrieves files without names, and it's a huge mess... I would love to recover my files with their respective names.

I tried with "gpart" but it shows 4 partitions that shows as "unknown" and I am not pretty sure this is the best way.

Comment: So you were expanding the second partition on the left?  That involves a drag left, then expand right.  At what point did you lose power? Did you keep the original sector starts/ends of your two partitions? A little more detail would help us make reasonable suggestions.

Comment: Sure, thanks for your answer @ubfan1. Yes, I was expanding the second partition to the left, gparted was dragging all to the left. Mmmh... I would say it should have 50% more or less done, like 400GB moved. Original sectors starts/ends on my two partitions? What do you mean?

Comment: A listing of the partitions' starts,ends,sizes may be had via gdisk -l /dev/nvme0n1   etc.

Comment: Oh, I just only can tell you the first partition (on the left) deleted manually had 200 GB, and the second 800GB (the HDD has 1TB). I don't have the start and the end sectors from the partition I want to recover.

Comment: The issue is that the data was half copied. So may be difficult or impossible to recover. This is why with any partition chamge, good backups are suggested. Was partition both data & system? You do not need to recover system as that is something you can reinstall,

Comment: testdisk might find the original partitions, or you might just be able to remake them with a partition tool like gdisk, 2048 is the usual start of partition 1, then try usign +200G for the ending. Second starts when first left off, to end. Seems like your partition info is garbage anyway, so I don't think making a new partition table will hurt. DO NOT make any filesystems or format. With luck, the original second partition is still just sitting there.

Comment: It was just data. Mmmh...I'm trying with testdisk. I didn't know about partition tools as gdisk, maybe I can still recover my files (at least, most of them). So, making a new partition without any format, maybe I can recover some of my files...mmmh, I'm gonna try it.

Comment: I did a quick search to seek my lost partition and I found it with the same name, but when I list all files from it, there's no files in there. Just a file called "Epic" and two folders, one is ".Trash-1001" and the other "lost+found". If I did a deep search, I'll found more or this is what I need to keep searching my files but doing another step?

Comment: Hi, @ubfan1. Can you answer the question so I choose you as good answer? I finally did it and I can fix this problem :) all it was with testdisk. I did a deep search and I tried with all partitions it found, and one of them works! So I was able to recover all my files.

Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

testdisk might find the original partitions. Do a deep search and try all the partitions it finds.  One of them may have your files.

A manual approach might help/work too. You remake your orignal partitions with a partition tool like gdisk, 2048 is the usual start of partition 1, then try using +200G for the ending. Second starts when first left off, to end. Seems like your partition info is garbage anyway, so I don't think making a new partition table will hurt. DO NOT make any filesystems or format. With luck, the original second partition is still just sitting there.

And the easiest would be to set up new partitions and restore from backup ;^)

Answer (score 1):

Expanding a partition should not normally result in data loss.  It's also quite fast even for a large partition.  But moving the start of a partition, which it sounds like you were doing, will if it's interrupted.  Unfortunately it's not easy to figure out where it was up to and resume from there.  If the new and old position of the partition don't overlap, then you could just restore the old partition in place by restoring the old partition table, but then you would still need to know where the old partition started (you could try using testdisk to find where the old partition started).

So I guess your options are, if you have the technical knowledge to piece together what I've alluded to above and attempt a MacGyver repair, do it.  Or, you could reinstall and restore from backups.  Or, take it to a data recovery specialist.